# Is Hibernate session save asynchronous?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class hierarchy mapped to DB tables, say `A->B->C`. `A` holds primary key and `B/C` refer to it for their rows.
I'm saving an object of `C`. So Hibernate will create a record for `A`, then `B` and `C`. Is this correct? (I'm not using transactions). I'm using Hibernate `3.2.6 GA`.

Question: is this `synchronous` or `asynchronous`? I assumed that it will be synchronous so it won't return before all these rows are saved. However it seems that even if it returns, some table is still being updated. So e.g. if I query for a `C` object after saving it, I get the state for `A` and `B` but get empty state for `C`. No error is returned anywhere and when I manually check the DB, all data is correctly seen there.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: It's proprietary so can't share. Really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is **synchronous**. Mostly, asynchronous behavior is handled by framework itself. Developers trying to implement asynchronous behavior can lead to unpredictable results. In case you dont see expected properties updated then please check code and corresponding sql generated by hibernate.

Also, asynchonous here means that hibernate will update some entities and flush/sync them in one go with database. It never means that parts of data getting updated at different times. This behavior will lead to inconsistent database state.